# Getting rid of hardcoded strings in JavaScript with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, hardcoded, magic-string

We have a few problems in a project I am working on, where we have a lot of JavaScript files, where we have hardcoded URLs to controller actions.

1. Hardcoded URLs are proned to mistyping
2. Hardcoded URLs in JavaScript scripts will cause a breakage if the related controller or action's name is changed
3. Tools like ReSharper (to my knowledge) can't statically analyse it's way to saying the an action is not used, if the URLs pointing to it are hardcoded.

**Question(s)**

How can we avoid using hardcoded URLs in JavaScript ? - are there any existing frameworks out there that could solve this problem ?

Look forward to hearing your insight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to pass urls to js code files from views with using url helpers.
Modify your js files to use one of module pattern.

First way - importing of global variables:

js

```
(function (url) {
    // your code 
}(external_url));
```

view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var external_url = '@Url.Action("action", "controller")'; // define global variable `external_url` with helper. This should be defined before script run.
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js" />
```

Second way - exporting module:

```
var module = (function (url) {
    // your code 
}(external_url));
```

view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    module('@Url.Action("action", "controller")');
</script>
```