# How can I access asp net inside a separate JS file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I write some value inside a separate JS file?

just an example:

```
// this is my file.js
var url = @Url.Action("foo");
var x = @Model.X
var y = @varY
```

If this is not possible what workaround can i take?

Comment: Use functions and call them from razor page. Because this is not possible. This property is available for Razor Engine...

Comment: No, you should pass this variables from view. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394880/getting-rid-of-hardcoded-strings-in-javascript-with-asp-net-mvc/17396877#17396877)